# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'err' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I have a React application with a Node.js backend.

I have this route on the backend:

```
router.put(
  '/testimonial/:testimonialId/:action',
  [authenticate, validateUser],
  async (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.action === 'ACCEPT') {
      const { err, status, data } =
        await notificationController.acceptTestimonial(
          req.params.testimonialId,
          req.user._id
        );
      res.status(status).send({ err, data });
    } else if (req.params.action === 'REJECT') {
      const { err, status, data } =
        await notificationController.rejectTestimonial(
          req.params.testimonialId,
          req.user
        );
      res.status(status).send({ err, data });
    }
  }
);
```

These are the corresponding Controllers: (acceptTestimonial/rejectTestimonial)

```
const acceptTestimonial = async (testimonialId, userId) => {
  try {
    await Users.findOne({ _id: userId }, async function (err, creator) {
      if (err) return { err, status: 404, data: null };
      else {
        const updatedTestimonials = creator.testimonials.map((testimonial) => {
          if (testimonial._id == testimonialId) {
            testimonial.status = 'PUBLISHED';
          }
          return testimonial;
        });

        creator.testimonials = updatedTestimonials;
        await creator.save();
        return { err: null, status: 200, data: creator };
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return { err: err.toString(), status: 500, data: null };
  }
};
```

```
const rejectTestimonial = async (testimonialId, userId) => {
  try {
    await Users.findOne({ _id: userId }, async function (err, creator) {
      if (!creator)
        return { err: 'Creator not found!', status: 404, data: null };
      else {
        const updatedTestimonials = creator.testimonials.map((testimonial) => {
          if (testimonial._id === testimonialId) {
            testimonial.status = 'REJECTED';
          }
          return testimonial;
        });
        creator.testimonials = updatedTestimonials;

        await creator.save();
        return { err: null, status: 200, data: creator };
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return { err: err.toString(), status: 500, data: null };
  }
};
```

When this route runs and performs the operations, I get this error in the console

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'err' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

I'm unable to figure out what the problem is, is there a problem with destructuring or passing values ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your route, in both cases (if / else), I think you have mentioned `user` wrong (In if body `req.user._id` and in else body `req.user`). Can you confirm?

Comment: it might be `req.query.user` or `req.params.user` !!!

Comment: nvm, I fixed that. That wasn't the cause though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because, you aren't "returning" anything in `try` block of your controllers. The `return` statement is actually of callback function.

`await` is used to replace callback & `promise.then` so you have to `return` something in `try` block. You can achieve this like:

```
const rejectTestimonial = async (testimonialId, userId) => {
    try {
        // await Users.findOne({ _id: userId }, async function (err, creator) {
        //   if (!creator)
        //     return { err: 'Creator not found!', status: 404, data: null };
        //   else {
        //     const updatedTestimonials = creator.testimonials.map((testimonial) => {
        //       if (testimonial._id === testimonialId) {
        //         testimonial.status = 'REJECTED';
        //       }
        //       return testimonial;
        //     });
        //     creator.testimonials = updatedTestimonials;
    
        //     await creator.save();
        //     return { err: null, status: 200, data: creator };
        //   }
        // });

        //  instead of this
        //  do this

        const creator = await Users.findOne({ _id: userId });   // for "_id", you can also simply do: await User.findById(userId);
        
        if (!creator)
            return { err: 'Creator not found!', status: 404, data: null };

        // creator.testimonials.forEach((testimonial) => {
        //     if (testimonial._id === testimonialId)
        //         testimonial.status = 'REJECTED';
        // });

        const updatedTestimonials = creator.testimonials.map((testimonial) => {
            if (testimonial._id === testimonialId)
                testimonial.status = 'REJECTED';

            return testimonial;
        });

        creator.testimonials = updatedTestimonials;
        await creator.save();

        return { err: null, status: 200, data: creator };

    } catch (err) {
        return { err: err.toString(), status: 500, data: null };
    }
}
```

Here your controller is **returning** something in both try & catch cases!

Comment: this is not really updating the document in the db

Comment: in that case, you can replace that `creator.testimonials.forEach(...)` part with your code i.e. `const updatedTestimonials = creator.testimonials.map(...);  creator.testimonials = updatedTestimonials;`

Comment: oops sorry, its variable naming mistake, `user` should be `creator`. Updated the document

Answer (score 0):

I have this function

```
const deleteMsg = async (userId, messagesWith, messageId) => {
try {
    const user = await Chat.findOne({ user: userId });

    const chat = user.chats.find(
        chat => chat.messagesWith.toString() === messagesWith,
    );

    if (!chat) {
        return;
    }

    const messageToDelete = chat.messages.find(
        message => message._id.toString() === messageId,
    );

    if (!messageToDelete) return;

    if (messageToDelete.sender.toString() !== userId) {
        return;
    }

    const indexOf = chat.messages
        .map(m => m._id.toString())
        .indexOf(messageToDelete._id.toString());

    await chat.messages.splice(indexOf, 1);

    await user.save();

    return { success: true };
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return { success: false };
}
```

};

and calling it

```
const { success } = await deleteMsg(userId, messagesWith, messageId);
```

getting this error though

Cannot destructure property 'success' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

Comment: It is because in every **"if"** block you're returning nothing (`if (...) { return; }`). So there's no `"success"` in your call. Instead of `return;` do `return { success: false };` inside if blocks like you did in catch block